# how to display my website on facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have added my website on `page info` but it is not displayed on [page](https://m.facebook.com/matricole13).
I have tried viewing it from another profile but it is displaying only description and no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have just added your website in `website` tab but there is another and simple method to add your website link after description,You just need to edit description and add your website link at last , that's it now just refresh your page and you will get what you want.